# How can i convert an ndarray shape (32 by xxx) into a single column dataframe, while discarding the last ten objects of this array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, pytorch

After running a binary classification NLP model over a dataset with batch size of 32, i have an nparray of predictions of size 32 by 300 and the last batch is of size 24. i am trying to rearrange these values in a dataframe.

```
predictions.append(logits.argmax(1))
```

```
[array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0............
```

however, when i try to convert it to a dataframe,

```
df.labels = pd.DataFrame(predictions)
df.labels.head()
```

this is what i get

```
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
Name: labels, dtype: float64
```

1. i want to have the values as 1 or 0 integers, not floats
2. the final data batch of 32 has NaN from value 24 to 32, instead of being blank

Comment: did not work. i had already tried this in the past by passing 'int64'. i know for a fact that the column defaults to a float64 because of the last array which has 24 values instead of 32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column contains `NaN` it will always be of `float` type. The presence of `NaN` values explains therefore why the column is `float`.

You must have a dimension problem, your predictions variable is two dimensional, 32 x 10, you should flatten it first and then add your 24 elements, see documentions [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) :

```
predictions = predictions.flatten()

to_append = logits.argmax(1) # this is your array with 24 elements 
predictions = predictions.append(to_append)
```

What happens here is that whan you append a row of 24 elements to a DataFrame with 32 columns, the last columns from 23 to 32 will exist and will automatically be filled with NaN. See some examples [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-append/).

Why do you want to transform `NaN` to blank? If blank means an empty string, you shouldn't do that, as you will mix float and string in your column.

If you want Integer values. You should make an imputation of the `NaN` values with a constant Integer value (let us say 888):

```
df = df.fillna(888)
```

Then you can transform all to int using the function [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) :

```
df = df.astype('int16')
```

Comment: let me clarify. i did not set the column values as NaN. the column does not exist until i try to convert the nparray into a dataframe. what i want it to do is to rearrage the e.g [32] * 10 + [24] nparray into a single column dataframe of len(df)= 344.  but instead, it converts it into an array of len(df)352, and fils up the last 8 values with NaN, thus converting my original type into a float.

Comment: You have an array of arrays, you should make a flatten before converting into a DataFrame. What is the shape of `predictions` before append ? 320 ? And after append 344 ? You must have a dimension problem here.

Comment: maybe i didnt explain sufficiently well. here are model predictions in 300 batches of  32. and the last one a batch of 24.      array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]) array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]      i want to combine them into a single dataframe column. am i clearer now?

Comment: You try to add a row of a 24 columns to a DataFrame with 32 columns, If you do that, the 24 columns will be added at the begining and the last columns (25 to 32) will be filled with NaN. That is how DataFrames work, the shape (lenght) of the columns or rows will not change. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was what worked for me.

```
predictions.append(logits.argmax(1))
flat_predictions = np.concatenate(predictions, axis=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=flat_predictions, columns=["gold_label",])
```

```
    gold_label
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
...
```